# Selenium remote run java.io.IOException: GOAWAY received

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

My selenium test run working on my local, but when I run my test on selenium grid remote driver

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '4.5.0', revision: 'fe167b119a'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.0-52-generic', java.version: '16.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [cd7d6eddadb63fba82cab0c5fb4e3e8c, executeScript {script=var viewPortHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);var elementTop = arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;window.scrollBy(0, elementTop-(viewPortHeight/2));, args=[{ELEMENT=810020af-124b-457f-8902-ffd409b790d2, element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=810020af-124b-457f-8902-ffd409b790d2}]}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 106.0.5249.119, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 106.0.5249.61 (511755355844..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.kpPBv2}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:36673}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: none, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(manual, http=http://s..., se:cdp: ws://192.168.130.19:4444/se..., se:cdpVersion: 106.0.5249.119, se:vnc: ws://192.168.130.19:4444/se..., se:vncEnabled: true, se:vncLocalAddress: ws://192.168.130.19:7900, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: cd7d6eddadb63fba82cab0c5fb4e3e8c

Caused by: java.io.IOException: /192.168.130.157:45902: GOAWAY received
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:568)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.jdk.JdkHttpClient.execute(JdkHttpClient.java:236)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: /192.168.130.157:45902: GOAWAY received
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection.handleGoAway(Http2Connection.java:1007)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection.handleConnectionFrame(Http2Connection.java:872)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection.processFrame(Http2Connection.java:747)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.frame.FramesDecoder.decode(FramesDecoder.java:155)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection$FramesController.processReceivedData(Http2C
```

Can you help me understanding the problem?

My selenium 4.5.0 and grid version is 4.6.0 when I upgrade my version 4.8.0 same problem is continue.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @GuilhermeMachado Any solution found for this ?

Comment: @ali Any solution found

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the issue after upgrading my framework to Java 17 and Selenium version 4.14+, where the jdk-http-client became the default Java library, and HTTP/2 became the default version.
The problem, in my case, arose due to an incompatibility between the default HTTP/2 version in Selenium and the server's support for HTTP/1.1.
Starting from Selenium 4.14.1, you can set the version in the HTTP Client Config, which resolved the issue in my case.

```
            ClientConfig config = ClientConfig
                    .defaultConfig()
                    .baseUrl(seleniumGridUrl) // here grid url should be specified
                    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1.name()); // set HttpClient version


            driver = RemoteWebDriver
                    .builder()
                    .oneOf(new ChromeOptions())
                    .config(config)
                    .build();
```